# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute 'RegisterShape'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using TensorFlow 2.1.0-dev20191125

Unfortunately I can't compile a simple example with error:

> "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no
>   attribute 'RegisterShape'"

My source code:

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops as _ops
_ops.RegisterShape("GRUBlockCell")(None)
```

Is it looks like incorrectly installed `TF`?

Answer (score 1):

Shape functions for core `ops` were moved to C++ via `REGISTER_OP(...).SetShapeFn(...)`. So you may have to first create/register your operation in `C++`.

A detailed guide can be found in the official doumentation [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op)