# Why am I not able to import TFLearn?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tflearn

I'm trying to import TFLearn with this simple code:

```
import tflearn
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute 'RegisterShape'
```

I've got installed the following versions of programs:

Python 3.7.6 64 bit
Tensorflow 2.1.0
TFlearn 0.3.2

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here:
[AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute 'RegisterShape'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59043649/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-python-framework-ops-has-no-attribute-regis)

Maybe you can find help there.

Comment: Thank you Harishankar, I had already read that answer to the question. But it seems like they are trying to create an operation. Is it normal that this is happening just by trying to import a package?

Comment: The ```tflearn``` package didn't receive any updates from  Jan 10, 2019, and ```tensorflow``` package receives updates frequently. Maybe the developers of ```tflearn``` didn't keep up with ```tensorflow``` development. And I think that ```tflearn``` is not appropriate for use, considering the situation. Maybe choose another deep learning library.